# How to iterate through lines in a text file and compare it to other line (C++)

Tags: c++, string, file, vector, input

I've created a simple logging in/ signing up program that reads and writes from files. It asks to log in or sign up and if you choose sign up, it writes to a seperate text file with the credentials (username and password). If you choose log in, it *SHOULD* compare your credentials with all the credentials in the file and say if it is a valid account.

Here is the code (shockingly long I know; I'm only 13 so I kinda suck at this):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

// Function that gets username and password from the user
vector<string> askForCredentials(){
    string username, password;

    cout << "Please enter a username: ";
    getline(cin, username);
    // Repeatedly asks the question until the input has no spaces
    while(username.find(" ") != string::npos){
        cout << "No spaces in the username!" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter a username: ";
        getline(cin, username);
    }

    //Again
    cout << "Please enter a password: ";
    getline(cin, password);
    while(password.find(" ") != string::npos){
        cout << "No spaces in the password!" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter a password: ";
        getline(cin, password);
    }

    return {username, password};
}

int main() {
    //Declares variable for user input
    string request;
    cout << "Would you like to log in or sign up? ";
    getline(cin, request);

    //While the input is not log in or sign up it repeats the question
    while(request != "log in" && request != "sign up"){
        cout << "That is not a valid answer. Would you like to log in or sign up? ";
        getline(cin, request);
    }

    //If the user wants to sign up...
    if(request == "sign up"){
        //Creates a vector calling the askForCredentials function which asks user for username and password
        vector<string> credentials = askForCredentials();
        //Opens accounts text file in append mode
        ofstream accounts("current_accounts.txt", ios::app);

        //If the file opens than say account created successfully, otherwise say couldn't make account
        if(!accounts.is_open()){
            cerr << "Couldn't create account" << endl;
            return 0;
        } else{
            cout << "Account created successfully!" << endl;
        }

        //Appends username and password seperated by a space in the accounts file
        accounts << credentials[0] << " " << credentials[1] << " " << endl;
        accounts.close();
    }

    //If the user requests to log in...
    if(request == "log in"){
        //Creates vector with user input and says if file opens successfully or not
        vector<string> credentials = askForCredentials();
        ifstream accounts;
        accounts.open("current_accounts.txt");
        if(!accounts.is_open()){
            cerr << "Couldn't log in" << endl;
            return 0;
        }

    // Need help here

    return 0;
    }
}
```

My problem lies in the log in part. I basically need to iterate through every line of credentials in the current_accounts file and compare it to the entered credentials. If anyone could help me out on this it would be greatly appreciated! Also I can respond if you need more information.

Oh and also I would appreciate if you tell me how I could optimize but keep it readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the follwoing statement to your software:

```
        if (!accounts.is_open()) {
            cerr << "Couldn't log in" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        else {

            // Here we will store the status. Did we find the username and password or not
            bool found = false;

            // Temporary storage for username and password read from file
            std::string userName;
            std::string passWord;

            // In a loop, read all usernames and password
            while ((accounts >> userName >> passWord) and not found) {

                // Check, if the data is present
                if ((credentials[0] == userName) and (credentials[1] == passWord)) {

                    // If yes, indicate that and stop the loop
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            // Show result
            if (found) std::cout << "\nLogin successfull\n\n";


        }
```

Here we read all data from the file in a loop and compare it with the entered data.

The extractor operator >> will skip all white spaces, so reading is easy.

This will work, because you did not allow for spaces in username and password.

You could also read a complete line in a loop using `std::getline`, put the line into a `std::istringstream` and extract from there. This is normally the recommended approach, but in your case not necessary.

And your code is quite good. Especially the many comments are really good.

Design wise I would recommend to store the username and password in a struct and not in a vector of strings.